# Shipping calendar, cannot edit other peoples entries. Outlook/Exchange help

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

A user can create/delete/edit my own entries into the Shipping Calendar; however, the user cannot update/edit another person's entry, i.e. make changes to an event that Tom/Sandy created. What should I (domain admin) do to grant permissions that would allow her to edit other peoples calendar entries on this shipping calendar? Outlook 2003/Exchange 2003 help.

Answer (score 0):

The Permissions tab (right click -Properties-Permissions)on the public folder will let you select users or groups and apply specific permissions in a very granular fashion.  You can select from a list of predefined roles or apply permissions specifically.

This assumes you have the higher permission to set permissions on the folder.